# Passport 'logout()' not working as expected

Tags: session, express, passport.js

I have a simple authentication system where a user may log in, then log out.

I have many pages and many routes in my app, and every route has this general structure (I'm using my `dashboard.hbs` route here as an example):

```
router.get('/dashboard', ensureAuthenticated, function(req, res, next) {
  User.findOne({ username: req.user.username }, function(err, loggedInUser) {
    if (err) throw err
    else {
      res.render('dashboard', {
        user: loggedInUser
      })
    }
  })
});
```

Specifically, I'm assigning `loggedInUser` to `user` to use in my `dashboard.hbs` partial like so:

```
<h2 align="center">{{user.first_name}}'s Dashboard</h2>
```

When logging out, I simply use the `'/logout` route like so:

```
router.get('/logout', function(req, res, next) {
    req.logout()
    res.render('logout')
});
```

The problem with this approach is that I'm repeating `user: loggedInUser` in every route, and I'd like to refactor my code to DRY it up, and define the user that's logged in just once, and use that in every partial.

To help solve this problem, I did the following in my `server.js` file:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.locals.logged_in_user = req.user
  next();
});
```

Now, I'm able to use `logged_in_user` in any partial without having to assign it in a route.  This works fine everywhere, except when logging out.  When logging out, the `req.user` property (assigned as `logged_in_user`) is not immediately removed, and the login session is not immediately cleared.  I'm running the following code:

```
router.get('/logout', function(req, res, next) {
    req.logout()
    res.render('logout')
});
```

This is almost identical to the Passport documentation [here](http://passportjs.org/docs).

Once I hit the `/logout` route, I have to refresh the page for the login session to be cleared.  This was not the case when I was using `user: loggedInUser` in every route.  Now that it's refactored, it no longer works properly.

I should also note that my `layout.hbs` file includes this code:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">
  {{#if logged_in_user }}
    <li role="presentation"><a href="/dashboard">Dashboard</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="/logout">Log Out</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="/messages">Messages</a></li>
     <li role="presentation"><a href="/users/member">Profile</a></li>
  {{else}}
    <li role="presentation"><a href="/login">Login</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="/register">Register</a></li>
  {{/if}}
</ul>
```

Using the refactored style, how do I clear a user's login session?

**Update**

While `res.render('logout')` does not seem to work, I can just `res.redirect` the user to the login page, and display a message across the page (using `connect-flash`) that they have successfully logged out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `req.logout()` will clear `req.user` (it does `req.user = null`, basically), but your middleware created a reference to the original object, which is what `res.locals.logged_in_user` is still pointing to.

As for the session (`req.session.user`): that will be updated at the end of the response, so after `res.render('logout')` has been called. That's why using `res.redirect()` is a better way to clear the session after logging out.

Comment: For this type of situation, is using `res.redirect()` considered better practice than `res.render()`?  I ask because technically, I can still use `res.render('logout')` if I don't use `res.locals.logged_in_user = req.user`, and just define `user: loggedInUser` in every route in my app.

Comment: @Farid you can also override `logged_in_user` in the render call: `res.render('logout', { logged_in_user : null })`. If you have a specific "logged out" page, rendering a page instead of redirecting is fine.

Comment: That's a great idea.  I didn't think about that.  Thanks!